# Magento 2.4.5 uninstall language pack not working

Tags: magento2.4

I made my own language module and now i want to uninstall it. Even when i remove the folder and do a complete new deploy, the translations are stil there.

I get the error:

```
bin/magento i18n:uninstall jilco/language-nl_nl

Package language-nl_nl is not a Magento language and will be skipped.
Nothing is removed.
```

The name in composer.json is the same:

```
{
"name": "jilco/language-nl_nl",
"description": "NL taalpakket",
"version": "100.0.2",
"require": {
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
},
"type": "magento2-language",
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}
```

}

What is wrong in the command to uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That command (`bin/magento i18n:uninstall`) uninstalls only language packages that are provided as Composer packages and hosted in a server like packagist.org, github.com, repo.magento.com, and so on. If not, you must uninstall it manually by removing language package code from the file system.

The error when you run that command indicates your language package is not provided as Composer packages in a server. In other words, your language package is a local package (located in `app/i18n` directory).

So you must uninstall it manually by removing language package code from the file system and re-deploy static content:

Step 1: Remove the language package from `app/i18n` directory.
Step 2: Re-deploy static content. Note: you must remove `pub/static` and `var/view_preprocessed` before running the deploy command:

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend
rm -rf pub/static/frontend
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there was a language .csv in the theme files...

After removing that al the translations were gone